# Drupal: Cron runs but Autoresponder doesn't send email?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, cron

Within Drupal I have the Autoresponder module installed. I've configured cron to run twice a day which within the status report it's shown as being run successfully - however no emails are being sent from autoresponder....

If I then run cron manually then the emails are sent?

Any ideas very much appreciated.

Shane

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the watchdog log for any mail errors? You could also take a look at http://drupal.org/project/smtp which replaces php's mail() function with a call to your mail server. It also has a debugging mode that can help track down issues.